# Width of textView increasing as text is added—android

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a `<textView>` in android xml. When I add text to this textview, however, its width increases. I want its width to remain constant at exactly half the screen's width. How can I do this?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/decrypted"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:text=""/> <!--I want this to change without the entire width changing.-->
```

Comment: Add android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: That seemed to work! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/decrypted"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXTLONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


</LinearLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! All I needed to do was to add the android:layout_width="0dp". This worked well!